# MS word table of contents description is not lining up

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, alignment

I have a report where the description for one part of the table of contents does not line up correctly.  See attached image:

[image: Image of table of contents]

"f. Tensile Strength" is shifted left from all the other sections.  I usually just move it by hand but this is a template and I have to change it every time I have a new report and every time I update the field for a change.  I can not for the life of me figure out what is different about this one section.

Any idea how to shift it over correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your lines have a Word Style associated with them.  Word manages a block of text (nominally a paragraph) with Styles and you can assign a Style to a block of text.

Look at the Style for a working line and change the style of the bad line to the Style of a working line. That always works for me.

You can look at the horizontal ruler (add rulers if you need to) and you can also adjust indents on the ruler.

However you are better to use correct styles to fix the line.

Use a copy of the document to change so that if you need to, you can go back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

### A Table of Contents (TOC) is a field inserted with switches to identify which items in the text should be displayed.

By default it displays things that are in Heading Styles.The way the TOC, itself, is displayed is controlled by the TOC styles, with certain direct formatting in the text coming into the TOC.

Here is a link that may help you figure things out.

[Table of Contents Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm) by Suzanne Barnhill, MVP

Specifically, the tab set in your TOC 2 paragraph style is combining with the formatting of your multilevel list to not advance your text far enough. Try modifying the TOC 2 paragraph style so by removing a tab stop.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
I was able to fix it by moving the little L in the horizontal ruler for that line.  No idea how it fell out of position but it has been a problem for two years, as I keep using the report as a template for the next one.  All fixed.

Comment: You should consider marking our answers as helpful.